# Show the array of longitude and latitude by using GMap.NET.WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I want to show something like a path for arrays containing longitudes and latitudes in a C# windosform application. I am using the GMap.NET.WindowsForms Nuget package. I used the following code, but it marks the last one. Actually it shows the previous points too, but it refreshes to the next one until getting the final one.

```
double[] lats = { 10, 50, 60 };
double[] longs = { 40, 25, 10 };
int i = 0;
    
var markersOverlay = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("marker1");
    
var marker = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
                  new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latitude.Text), Convert.ToDouble(longitude.Text)),
                  GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.red_small);
    
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
       
foreach (var lat in lats)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{lat} , {longs[i]}");
    gmap.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, longs[i]);
    i++;
}
gmap.Zoom = Convert.ToDouble(zoom_level.Text);
gmap.Update();
gmap.Refresh();
```

How may I show all the specified lats and longs on the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to draw a route based on some coordinations. To draw a path on map you should create an overlay layer for it and then add create a route from coordinations and add it to this ovaerlay. A possible solution is like this:

```
   PointLatLng[] coords = new PointLatLng[]
   {
           new PointLatLng(10,40),
           new PointLatLng(50,25),
           new PointLatLng(60,10)
   };

   private void draw_path()
   {
       gmap.MapProvider = OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;

       GMapOverlay routeLayer = new GMapOverlay("routes");
       GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(coords , string.Empty);
       routeLayer.Routes.Add(route);
       gmap.Overlays.Add(routeLayer);

       //optional: show marker for route points
       GMapOverlay markersLayer = new GMapOverlay("markers");
       markersLayer.Id = "markers";
       foreach (PointLatLng coord in coords)
       {
           GMarkerGoogle gm = new GMarkerGoogle(coord, GMarkerGoogleType.red);
           gm.ToolTipText = coord.ToString();
           markersLayer.Markers.Add(gm);
       }
       gmap.Overlays.Add(markersLayer);

       gmap.ZoomAndCenterRoute(route);
   }
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1: Adding text to route segments using transparent marker with display-always tooltip**

```
private void draw_path()
{
    gmap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
    GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;

    GMapOverlay routeLayer = new GMapOverlay("routes");
    GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(coords,"Route Name"); // set a name for route
    routeLayer.Routes.Add(route);
    gmap.Overlays.Add(routeLayer);

    GMapOverlay markersLayer = new GMapOverlay("markers");
    markersLayer.Id = "markers";
    foreach (PointLatLng coord in coords)
    {
        GMarkerGoogle gm = new GMarkerGoogle(coord, GMarkerGoogleType.red);
        gm.ToolTipText = coord.ToString();
        markersLayer.Markers.Add(gm);
    }

    // adding transparent markers with display-always tooltip to simulate text for each segment
    for (int i = 1; i < coords.Length;i++)
    {
        double lat = (coords[i - 1].Lat + coords[i].Lat) / 2;
        double lng = (coords[i - 1].Lng + coords[i].Lng) / 2;
        GMarkerCross cm = new GMarkerCross(new PointLatLng(lat,lng));
        cm.Pen = new Pen(Color.Transparent);
        cm.ToolTipText = route.Name;
        cm.ToolTip.Offset = new Point(-20, 0);
        cm.ToolTip.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14f,FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
        cm.ToolTip.Foreground = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        cm.ToolTip.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
        cm.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;
        cm.ToolTip.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Transparent);
        markersLayer.Markers.Add(cm);
    }
    gmap.Overlays.Add(markersLayer);
    gmap.ZoomAndCenterRoute(route);
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2: Using precise formula to calculating midpoints.**

Using a simple average approach to calc midpoint as in flat geometry on a spherical surface is not accurate (as in update 1 to set midpoint markers).

In this update the precise formula is applied from [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate midpoints.

```
private PointLatLng MidPoint(PointLatLng point1, PointLatLng point2)
{
    double p1Lat = point1.Lat * Math.PI / 180d;
    double p1Lng = point1.Lng * Math.PI / 180d;
    double p2Lat = point2.Lat * Math.PI / 180d;
    double p2Lng = point2.Lng * Math.PI / 180d;
    
    double Bx = Math.Cos(p2Lat) * Math.Cos(p2Lng - p1Lng);
    double By = Math.Cos(p2Lat) * Math.Sin(p2Lng - p1Lng);
    double MidLat = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(p1Lat) + Math.Sin(p2Lat),
        Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Math.Cos(p1Lat) + Bx), 2d) + By * By));
    double MidLng = p1Lng + Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(p1Lat) + Bx);
    return new PointLatLng(MidLat * 180d / Math.PI, MidLng * 180d / Math.PI);
}
    
    
private void draw_path()
{
    gmap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
    GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
    
    GMapOverlay routeLayer = new GMapOverlay("routes");
    GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(coords, "Route Name"); // set a name for route
    routeLayer.Routes.Add(route);
    gmap.Overlays.Add(routeLayer);
    
    GMapOverlay markersLayer = new GMapOverlay("markers");
    markersLayer.Id = "markers";
    foreach (PointLatLng coord in coords)
    {
        GMarkerGoogle gm = new GMarkerGoogle(coord, GMarkerGoogleType.red);
        gm.ToolTipText = coord.ToString();
        markersLayer.Markers.Add(gm);
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < coords.Length; i++)
    {
        GMarkerCross cm = new GMarkerCross(MidPoint(coords[i - 1], coords[i]));
        cm.ToolTipText = route. Name;
        cm.ToolTip.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14f, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
        cm.ToolTip.Foreground = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        cm.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;
        markersLayer.Markers.Add(cm);
    }
    gmap.Overlays.Add(markersLayer);
    gmap.ZoomAndCenterRoute(route);
}
```

[image]

[image]

As the image shows, midpoints are still not exactly on the route. This might be due to slightly distortion of earth from perfect sphere.

A solution is to add more intermediate point in route (using MidPoint function) and put markers at these points, which also tends to more precise route.

Comment: Thanks Shahram jooni. What can I do to show the route name on tooltip the route? I mean instead of `string.Empty` in `GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(coords , string.Empty);` I want to put the route name and then show it when I point to its route by the mouse.

Comment: I was not able to set a caption for route or polygon. But, you can put empty marker(s) with tooltipmode=always to the markers layer to simulate this. I will update the answer to cover this.

Comment: Sorry. If I am not wrong I found out that `double lat = (coords[i - 1].Lat + coords[i].Lat) / 2; double lng = (coords[i - 1].Lng + coords[i].Lng) / 2;` does not exactly point to the midpoind of the specified points. Actually I want to make an arrow on the middle of two points, so I draw another path from the starting point to the midpoint of them. by using stroke dashstyle custom cap capabilities  But specially when the distance is big, it does not exactly coincide with the main route. Do you know how may I find the exact mid point?

Comment: @Javad-M, you are absolutely correct. Using flat geometry formula on spherical surface is wrong. But I just needed a rough approximation to put an invisible marker with a tooltip. Let me check Gmap.Net documents to see if there is a method to calculate this.

Comment: I checked the formula for calculating midpoints from [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Even with this precise formula the markers are not exactly on the line. I am not sure what is the exact cause. But may be the route is a projection or the distance between two points is too long. I will update the answer with this formula.